# Trying to compile with Codelite on OSX(Mountain Lion) gives missing headers

Tags: macos, wxwidgets, codelite

I am trying out some cross platform GUI environments and have am evaluating wxWidgets using codelite, but have gotten stuck at the very beginning.

I am very new at this, if its a stupid question please say so.

prerequisites are,

1. Using OSX Mountain Lion
2. Installed wxmac via home brew
3. Downloaded Codelite, created a wxWidgets Executable

I make a GUI project and try to install but get a bunch of missing header errors.

```
make[1]: wx-config: Command not found
g++  -c  "xxxx/helloworld/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall   -o ./Debug/main.o -I. -I. 
g++  -c  "xxxx/helloworld/MainFrame.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall   -o ./Debug/MainFrame.o -I. -I. 
In file included from xxxx/helloworld/MainFrame.h:3,
                 from xxxx/helloworld/MainFrame.cpp:1:
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:4:25: error: wx/settings.h: No such file or directory
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:5:27: xxxx/helloworld/main.cpp:1:20: error: wx/app.h: No such file or directory
xxxx/helloworld/main.cpp:2:22: error: wx/event.h: No such file or directory
In file included from xxxx/helloworld/MainFrame.h:3,
                 from xxxx/helloworld/main.cpp:3:
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:4:25: error: wx/settings.h: No such file or directory
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:5:27: error: wx/xrc/xmlres.h: No such file or directory
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:6:27: error: wx/xrc/xh_bmp.h: No such file or directory
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:7:22: error: wx/frame.h: No such file or directory
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:8:22: error: wx/sizer.h: No such file or directory
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:9:22: error: wx/panel.h: No such file or directory
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:10:21: error: wx/menu.h: No such file or directory
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:11:24: error: wx/toolbar.h: No such file or directory
xxxx/helloworld/main.cpp:4:22: error: wx/image.h: No such file or directory
In file included from xxxx/helloworld/MainFrame.h:3,
                 from xxxx/helloworld/main.cpp:3:
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:14: error: expected class-name before '{' token
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:16: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'wxPanel' with no type
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:16: error: expected ';' before '*' token
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:17: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'wxMenuBar' with no type
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:17: error: expected ';' before '*' token
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:18: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'wxMenu' with no type
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:18: error: expected ';' before '*' token
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:19: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'wxMenuItem' with no type
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:19: error: expected ';' before '*' token
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:20: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'wxMenu' with no type
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:20: error: expected ';' before '*' token
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:21: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'wxMenuItem' with no type
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:21: error: expected ';' before '*' token
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:22: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'wxToolBar' with no type
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:22: error: expected ';' before '*' token
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:25: error: 'wxCommandEvent' has not been declared
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:26: error: 'wxCommandEvent' has not been declared
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:29: error: expected `)' before '*' token
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h: In member function 'virtual void MainFrameBaseClass::OnExit(int&)':
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:25: error: request for member 'Skip' in 'event', which is of non-class type 'int'
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h: In member function 'virtual void MainFrameBaseClass::OnAbout(int&)':
xxxx/helloworld/wxcrafter.h:26: error: request for member 'Skip' in 'event', which is of non-class type 'int'
```

my guess would be to specify the folder that includes all of these, but am not sure where to find them.

Well to be honest I'm not sure if thats the right action at all, maybe I need to install or set something up, perhaps I shouldn't use homebrew and install by source

### Added

Thanks to VZ. I got it working, had to change some of the build settings, as bellow

1. Settings>BuildSettings>gnu g++>Tools>PATH Environment Variables set to

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

1. Set all the Compiler, Linker, Shared Object Linker settings to absolute path, so change

> g++

to

> /usr/bin/g++

and so forth.

This surely changes per setup of the machine so it probably shouldn't be followed to the letter, but should get you started.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you need to fix is the very first one:

```
make[1]: wx-config: Command not found
```

Make sure `wx-config` is in your path. Do **not** specify the include paths manually, this is not the right way to do it, you must use `wx-config`.

Comment: That defiantly got me in the right direction, after adding the correct environment variables, I had some other problems, but I made it to the point where the build completes! will post what I did in the question

Answer (score 0):

You probably would need to download wxWidgets source code distribution (2.9.4 from [this page](http://wxwidgets.org/downloads/) or latest source code from [SVN](http://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxWidgets/trunk)), unpack it, build libs from the source code

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

then reboot and after that try to build the Codellite.